# I'm getting “unusable disk space” error. while creating partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time in order to dual-boot it alongside Windows 7. I've freed up some space in my hard-drive, started the installation via USB and I'm having some problems in partitioning. So here's how the partition table looks

[image]

[image]

I go ahead and try to create a swap drive for 2GB, it creates the drive successfully but the remaining 98GB turns into unusable space and I can't create ext4 out of it. I tried reverting the changes this time first creating the 98GB of ext4 drive- it gets created but the remaining 4GB appears unusable so I can't create a swap drive out of it. I tried it with different sizes, still no good. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

MBR partitioning can only have 4 primary partitions.

Delete the swap partition you created, then create an extended partition filling the free space.

Then create logical drives within the extended partition for your linux install